# which file occurs this error in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am facing this error 
QueryException in Connection.php line 729: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'logistic_db.settings' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `settings` limit 1)

when i type http://localhost/bikeTest/public/home

Could you help me from which file  occurs this error

Comment: Need to mention i have remove table settings from database because i have no need this table current project

Answer (score 0):

This error means there is no table called `settings` in `logistic_db`

Comment: Yes i have removed this table because i have no need table and i dont want to use this one

Comment: I think you have models that use this table.

Comment: how i will find out which model i have use

Comment: could u help me if i share skype id sir

Answer (score 0):

In your model 'settings.php' do this.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Settings extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'settings'; 
}
```

It will work for your 'settings' table.

Comment: Sir i have no need this table settings and i am not sure from where this model is called when i try to call home controller.Is it possible to help me in TV

Comment: Please check carefully your error settings table it's not found.

Comment: Please check homeController.php and view page may be setting table called there